# Is there a way to bypass the 1 hour simulation limitation

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way I can bypass the simulation of the 1-hour duration limitation? My simulation does not require more than 1 hour but it indicated that I ran for more than 1 hr. I have already indicated 'Never' in the Model time section in the Simulation Experiment.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdNvP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdNvP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the info msg, the free PLE version limits you to 1 hr. Your options:

1. get a full license
2. Do not use the Material Handling library (I think it allows longer runtimes without it)
3. Rerun the same model several times and accumulate the results (i.e. create a freeform parameter variation experiment that reruns the 1hr model 24 times --> aggregate the results --> 1 day done
4. If you are not relying on the physical aspects of the material handling library, you could change the logic such that 1 model minute actually represents a week, a month or whatever --> now the model still runs for 1 virtual hr but it *represents* a longer time frame